# Are bunya-bunya nuts safe to eat if the shells are moldy?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, mold, australian-cuisine

We recently harvested a bunch of [bunya-bunya cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_bidwillii) and set them aside for a while to wait for them to split open.  Unfortunately, we forgot about them for a while and it rained in the meantime, so not only did they split open, but they started rotting.

However, the nuts themselves are double encased, [first in a husk](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_2auPgkwYYKY/TVSV0aq8LoI/AAAAAAAABhk/w0rRbiGnTdA/s320/01%2BAraucaria%2Bbunya%2Bnut%2Bin%2Bhusk%2BFeb%2B2011.jpg) and then [in a leathery shell](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-DL_Vc0zJPgQ/TVSWNt1r42I/AAAAAAAABh8/WASqmdcHA6U/s320/01%2BAraucaria%2Bbunya%2Bnut%2Broasted%2Band%2Bshelled%2BFeb%2B2011.jpg).  I've discarded the obviously spoiled ones, but **are the nuts still OK to eat if the shell is a bit moldy**?  I tried opening a few, and the nuts showed no obvious signs of spoilage, but they were also a bit squishier than usual.

For what it's worth, Aborigines are said to have [buried the nuts in creeks](http://toowoombaplants2008.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/no-fuss-bunya-nut-cookery.html) and eaten them after fermentation, but I'd prefer my bunya nuts unfermented ;)

Comment: I'd no idea these were edible. Bunya pines may also be found in San Jose, CA: http://www.siliconvalley.com/salpizarro/ci_13203179